# Trying to generalize the solving of a functional equation

Tags: analysis, functional-equations

If we take the following functional equation for $f : \mathbf{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$, such as for any $(x,y), f(xy) = xf(y)+yf(x)$, the solution is trivial if $f$ is derivable (we just derive the equation...). If $f$ is derivable only in $0$, we also can find the solution by considering what happens around $0$.
I was wondering if we could do something also if we know that $f$ is derivable in $a, a > 0$. Stuck there. Any help?

Comment: What is meant by "derivable"?  Should it be "differentiable"?

Comment: Oups yes, poor english translation. "Differentiable" is the right word. Thank you.

Comment: I can see $f(0)=f(1)=0$ in general and that one solution is $f(x)=0$, but it might help if you said what your differentiable overall or at $0$ led to.

Comment: Technically if f executes differentiation, that means it's an operator on a space of functions and not a mapping from $R^+$ to $R$, right?

Comment: Recall a solution to [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) that is continuous at a single point is automatically ($\mathbb{R}$-)linear, and consider $g\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R};t\mapsto e^{-t}f(e^t)$.

Comment: Thank you user1035... Very useful !